# How to append only new items in html/heex from a RSS feed?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

In the `mount` method, I call an RSS feed for the first time and render all results it returns. In the `handle_info` method, I perform a `Process.send_after` call to retrieve that same RSS feed every 5 seconds. The RSS feed contains the original items returned during `mount` but it will also include new items not returned during `mount`.

With this implementation, the list rendered in the initial `mount` just gets overridden with the items from `handle_info`. How can I append only the new items in the html/heex and retain the existing items so the UI shows a growing list of items?

Edit:

Ideally, the `handle_info` method will return a LiveView [stream](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#stream/4) but *stream items are temporary and freed from socket state immediately after the render/1 function is invoked* Due to this, there is no reference to the previous retrieved RSS feed items and it cannot be determined which RSS items have been rendered on the client and which RSS items are considered "new" to the client.

If `handle_info` returns an `assign`, access to the previous rendered items are available in the `socket` so new items can be determined. But the large number of records will cause issues and the new items are appended to the end of the rendered list. Users now have to keep scrolling to the bottom of the page to see the new items.

Any suggestions on how a `stream` can access previously returned data or how an `assign` can prepend new items to the top of the page without scrolling is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you keep track of the RSS feed items in the assigns of the LiveView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much context, I believe you can find the answer in the [basic example of the LiveView docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-example).

You need to keep the RSS feed items in the assigns of your LiveView. You can set the inital items and schedule the first update during mount

```
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
  if connected?(socket), do: Process.send_after(self(), :update_from_feed, 5_000)
  
  items = call_rss_feed()
  {:ok, assign(socket, :rss_items, items}
end
```

and update the assigns accordingly in the `handle_info`:

```
def handle_info(:update_from_feed, socket) do
  new_items = call_rss_feed()

  # here you need to add the logic of merging socket.assigns.items and new_items
  items = ...

  {:noreply, assign(socket, :items, items)}
end
```

EDIT (as more context was added to the question):

As the usage of `stream` is preferred, I see two possibilities:

1. Set the [`:reset`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#stream/4-resetting-a-stream) option of `stream/4` to `true` and always pass the full list of retrieved RSS feed items. Additionally, the items could be ordered from newest to oldest and an appropriate [`:limit`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#stream/4-limiting-a-stream) could be set to the stream.
2. Keep track of the retrieved RSS feed items in the LiveView assigns and implement logic to filter only new items based on what was retrieved earlier. The you can just pass the new items to the stream with `stream(socket, :rss_items, new_items, at: 0)` as you want to prepend them. Setting a limit might still be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not adding much context. I'm actually implementing this via [stream](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#stream/3)

Comment: I see. Can you add more context to your question? That would help to better answer the question.

Comment: Yes, thanks for following up, hope the additional information helps. With your answer, new items are appended to the bottom. Is there a way to prepend so new items appear on top?

Comment: I'm also interested into stream, so I'll have look into it.

Regarding the order of the items: you can apply any logic on `items` before assigning them, e.g. `items = new_items ++ socket.assigns.items`

Comment: I updated the answer with two idea of how to achieve this using `stream`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jakobfp. I ended up just passing the full list of RSS feed items during each stream. Phoenix LiveView stream is smart enough to know that passing in items that have already been rendered doesn't require any UI updates so the only UI updates that do occur are new items which I don't need to track. Overall, the code is much simpler, you can review it here: https://github.com/hbcondo/last10k_liveview